# Table doesn't exist when deployed in server hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

When i deploy the web app on test server (it works fine on localhost ), this BLO_BlOCKED_MOBILES table at the given line of code.

```
Query query = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(
            strQuery.append(" INSERT INTO BLO_BlOCKED_MOBILES (BLO_CUSTOMER_ID_FK,BLO_MOBILE,BLO_NEWMOBILE,BLO_PASSPORT,BLO_STATUS,BLOCKED_BY,BLOCKED_AT ) "
             +"VALUES( "+customer.getId() +", '"+ oldMobile +"','"+newMobile+"','"+customer.getPassportNo()+"','Y','user',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)" ).toString());
    mtmrsLogger.info(query.toString());
    int affectedRows = query.executeUpdate();
```

The db is in mysql and app uses hibernate,struts 1 and spring. I created this new table ,
added this on hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 < mapping class="com.mtmrs.model.branch.BlockedMobile"/>
```

and created the model file BlockedMobile.java

and when it is used, the below error comes.

```
WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table 'merchantrade.blo_blocked_mobiles' doesn't exist
```

Please let me know if the information is insufficient. I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: Does your test server use the same MySQL database as your localhost does?

Comment: yes it does, i copied the same tablestructure and recreated the table on the test server db as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peraphs the two DB (on your localhost server and on test server) are different. So the test server has not got your table.

Comment: I dropped the test db and restored whole db into test platform. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, either the table `blo_blocked_mobiles` or the scheme `merchantrade` does not exist on the MySQL database on the test server.